# Bootrap with a div with overflow-y scrolling results in horizontal scrolling for webpage

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an HTML page (using Bootstrap 3) with a div with the following HTML:

`style="overflow-y:scroll; height:500px;"`

This result in the DIV having a scroll bar (because it has a lot of contents).

My page has 12 columns. When I don't have this div with overflow-y scrolling, the entire webpage page (not the div) has a scrolling horizontal scrollbar. I think the extra horizontal width is actually equal to the amount of additional space required by the scrollbar in the div (maybe bootstrap doesn't account for the width of scrollbars inside of divs for calculating its page widths?). Anyway, no matter how much I shrink and enlarge my webpage (on a huge monitor), there are still horizontal scrollbars. Anyone have any suggestions on waht I can do to get rid of the annoying horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

the scroll bar width is not included in the width of your div, unless you explicitly specify it to be that way with box-sizing: border-box.

very good browser support for box-sizing now, but you will still want to use the vendor prefixes:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by vendor prefixes?

Comment: vendor prefixes- are a way for browser makers to add support for new CSS features in a sort of testing and experimentation period. Browser prefixes are used to add new features that may not be part of a formal specification and to implement features in a specification that hasn’t been finalized.

Comment: Do I add this style to the div or to the html page? Because I added it to the style of the div and it didn't do anything.

Comment: box-sizing will affect the scroll bar position for the element that has the scroll bar attached to it